# Solving the error of "docker build" not accesing package.json

Tags: docker

I am trying to build an image for an express app and I have issues running the command. The error indicates that the `package.json` file is not accessible. Please look at the `structure error` below.

```sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:8-alpine
 ---> 2b8fcdc6230a
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d0f2d783ba5a
Step 3/7 : COPY package*.json ./
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

Also, the docker file is shown below:

```
FROM node:8-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Then lastly the file structure is shown below:

[image: This the file structure in my VSCode]

I'd like any assistance possible. Thanks.

Comment: What command are you running to build the image?

Comment: Depends on how you are running `docker build` command, can you check are you in the correct directory if you are running this on your laptop or any build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `docker build .` and it will run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the Node.JS version you are trying to use in the docker file, i'm not entirely sure if this is the case but I have used this docker file with my node.js express application and it seemed to work. Give it a shot.

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Also what command are you using to build the image?

Answer (score 0):

Use `COPY ./package*.json ./` like this in dockerfile.